# Get a list of URLs from large document

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink

I am trying to get a list of URLs "https://www.crocodiletrading.co.uk/" from an HTM file, I also need to get anything that comes after the main URL for example /blog/name-of-blog etc.

I am using Notepad++ and Regex to try and accomplish this but I am struggling. I don't really understand Regex.

I've tried something like this: `.*?(https\:\/\/www\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\-]+)`

Can anyone let me know how I can accomplish this?

I'm getting a list of the URLs that have been flagged as broken so I can then use this to set up 301 redirects.

Here is the [HTML FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11kWkNjo9ZDwpAJ8or0zoZDpgmH-hSk_1/view?usp=sharing) if anyone wants to take a look.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, why don't you parse the document, and then get them all hrefs with javascript

Comment: Do you have a guide somewhere that I could follow to try this? @ezhupa99

Comment: Please explain what exactly you need and provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I need to get all URLs that contain www.crocodiletrading.co.uk and anything that precedes it and get the list of URLs on its own line using REGEX - I'm not good at all with Regex so I am not sure what kind of reproducing example I can provide you. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: But I can only see two urls like that, try `you_big_text.match(/https?:\/\/www\.crocodiletrading\.co\.uk(?:\/[^"<>\n]*)?/g)`. They are in `<a href="https://www.crocodiletrading.co.uk/" TARGET=_blank>https://www.crocodiletrading.co.uk/</a> (8773 URLs)`. So, is that all you need?

Comment: Yes and no. If you see in the document some links have/blog/ after crocodiletrading.co.uk/ I also need to grab those.

Comment: Ok, I see, I missed some because the file is too big. So, all those with `blog/`? That is, `text.match(/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?crocodiletrading\.co\.uk\/blog\/[^"<>\n]*/g)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing instead, using good old jQuery to grab the URLs that contained crocodiletrading.co.uk

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() { 
var arr = [];
i = 0;

jQuery('a[href*="crocodiletrading.co.uk"]').each(function() {
    arr[i++] = jQuery(this).attr('href');
});

var list = '<ul class="myList"><li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-all" tabindex="-1">' + arr.join('</a></li><li>') + '</li></ul>';
console.log(list);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This function prints all the links that are inside all anchor tags (<a **href="link to some page"**></a>)

```
const getAllLinks = () => {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    links.forEach(link => {
        console.log(link.href);
    })
}
```

Comment: That's one way of getting them, but some links are not "https://www.crocodiletrading.co.uk/" and I don't want to grab those. @ezhupa99

Comment: From the regex you provided you didn't filter any url, but anyway if you have a pattern on which URLs you might be interested in just provide it and see what I can do,

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it may be helpful ,

Find: `^[\s\S]+?(https://www.crocodiletrading.co.uk/).*\n*(blog.*\d+).*`

Replace All: `$1$2`